# Listbox WPF item background color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the background color of ListBoxItem

After search I decide to use this

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Blue" />
            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                             Color="Blue" />

        </ListBox.Resources>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf4</TextBlock>
    </ListBox>
```

When a listboxitem is focused, the background is blue as expected, but when the selected listboxitem loses focus, the background turns gray. How can I make the background remain blue when it loses focus?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you mean just when its selected but inactive try `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

```
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Blue" />
        <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Blue" />

    </ListBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think we both read the question the same way LOL, I think OP just wants `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>fdfsdf4</TextBlock>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: If I do this, I'll get all listbox item blue. My task is selected listboxitem in focused and defocused state must be blue. But I've got blue color when focused and get gray color when defocused

Answer (score 1):

if you think the system color keys are not working for you then you can force it by creating new style for ListboxItems as like below.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to select the color for the active/inactive items of a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="lbExample" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <...>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Resources>
            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AntiqueWhite" />
            </Style>

            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MaterialDesignThemes and Caliburn Micro to make a ListBox that can have multiple selections. None of these other answers worked.  What did work for me was in the ViewModel.xaml:

```
<ListBox Padding="2" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="Field1Items" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ListBoxItemBackground}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Then having this class to encapsulate all my items:

```
public class MultiSelectItem : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public MultiSelectItem (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        _isSelected = false;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ListBoxItemBackground);
        }
    }

    public string ListBoxItemBackground
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsSelected)
                return "#e0e0e0";
            return "Transparent";
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and in the ViewModelClass:

```
public BindableCollection<MultiSelectItem> Field1Items
{
    get
    {
        return _field1Items;
    }
}
```